# Why my PhpMailer code send same email two times?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I have tried almost all solutions from StackOverflow community but unfortunately It doesn't help. I am using PhpMailer, and it sends email two times in contact form. Can anyone please help instead of marking my question as flag?

I have tried these Methods

```
$mail->ClearAddresses();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
```

HTML form:

```
<form class="con-form" method="post" action="/contact-action.php">
// Inputs
</form>
```

Contact-action.php file:

```
<?php
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

        require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
        require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
        require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';

        $recip_address = "info@yourdomain.com";
        $name       = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['name'])); 
        $sub        = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['subject']));
        $email      = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email'])); 
        $message    = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['message']));        

        if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($message)) {
                    http_response_code(400);
                    $msg = 'Please complete the form and try again.';
                    echo $msg;
                    exit;
        }

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
             'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
             )
         );

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
        $mail->addAddress($recip_address);     // Add a recipient 

        //Content
        $mail->Subject = $sub;
        $mail->Body    = "You have been contacted by: ".$name. "
        <br>E-mail: ".$email. "
        <br>Message: ".$message;
        $mail->AltBody = 'Body text';
        $mail->isHTML(true);                   // Set email format to HTML
        //$mail->send();

        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "We couldn't send your message.";
        } else {
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } 

        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        $mail->ClearAttachments();
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
var form = $('.con-form');
    var message = $('.contact-msg');
    var form_data;
    // Success function
    function done_func(response) {
        message.fadeIn().removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
        message.text(response);
        setTimeout(function () {
            message.fadeOut();
        }, 50000);
        form.find('input:not([type="submit"]), textarea').val('');
    }
    // fail function
    function fail_func(data) {
            message.fadeIn().removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');
            message.text(data.responseText);
            setTimeout(function () {
                message.fadeOut();
            }, 5000);
        }
    form.submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form_data
            })
            .done(done_func)
            .fail(fail_func);
        });
```

Expected output is recepient should receive an email. It receives the email but receiving two times.

Comment: please, at first have look if the form is submitted only once.

Comment: maybe u submitted the form twice.. how many times did u test this?

Comment: Your code look OK check your form

Comment: Are you using ajax to submit the form?

Comment: Thank you all for your response. Form only submitted once. I have tried for almost 10-15 times

Comment: @jeroen yes I am using AJAX. I am editing my question and adding AJAX code.

Comment: Then you probably need to cancel the default / regular form submit.

Comment: @jeroen Can you please check now my new added code?

Comment: Is `<form class="con-form"` vs `var form = $('.cont-form');` just a typo you introduced while posting here?

Comment: @04FS yes just typo. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Unless your PHP part is in some sort of loop, it makes no sense why this would send the mail twice. (And if it is not in a loop, then calling `ClearAddresses` _after_ the mail has already been send can’t achieve much either.) Please go check in your browser dev tools, network panel, if there is really just one request to the PHP script happening when you submit your form.

Comment: It's quite common for browser plugins to cause repeat submissions. The way to confirm that is to append a random number to your subject line, or to look at your logs to see the multiple requests. Also, don't suppress certificate verification, fix it properly - read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide for help on that.

Comment: Thank you all for great help and your contribution! Appreciate all of your responses. My issue has been solved! I followed @jeroen suggestion to remove default form submit and it worked. Thank you so much